# Como checar se um número é negativo em JS através de uma função

Tags: javascript

Eu ainda estou começando a aprender JS, por isso apenas quero que me explique e me dê exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

```
function verificaNegativo(valor) {
    if (valor < 0) {
        alert("O numero é negativo");
    } else {
        alert("O numero é Positivo");
    }
}
```

Você pode usar uma simples função que verifica se o numero passado é menor que 0.

Comment: Muito bom, parece besteira, mas tem horas que dá uns brancos.

Answer (score 1):

O conceito de número negativo é ser menor que zero.

Na programação, há "testes condicionais", que executam uma ação caso seja verdade.
Em JS e na maioria das linguagens, é feito dentro de uma estrutura `if` e `else`.

Você poderá fazer no seu código desse jeito:

```
if(numero < 0)
```

Vale lembrar que `numero` é uma variável, e deve ser definida previamente.